# centos5 maximum memory setting for all users

Tags: centos, memory, limit

I'm using Centos5 for operating server and the machine has limited memory. There are many users using the server and some of them are running programs which use a lot of RAM.

When I check the used memory using top, both the RAM and the Swap are occupied by only a small number of users. So, I would likely to enforce a memory usage limit for each user.

How can I enforce such a limitation?

Answer (score 0):

/etc/security/limits.conf

Is the place where you can set such `ulimit` related defauls or user specific limits.

They will get active on new user sessions.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry I forgot it. I can't find accept button. Maybe time is over. I also tried to vote but my reputation is too small I can't do (less than 15).

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use CloudLinux, as your exact issues are what it was designed to balance.  Many shared hosting evironments add this kernel module to limit their own user resource usage as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, it looks nice but CloudLinux looks not free software. Maybe I can solve problem by changing limits.conf .